# React hook toggle bool value on nested property

Tags: react-hooks, boolean

I have looked at lots of similar questions for this but none of them seem to solve my issue.

I am using a react hook to open a modal pop-up which will play a video. I create an initial state with a boolean for whether the modal will show or not, and an additional property to pass in video urls.

I've been trying to use setState to initially toggle the boolean but it only seems to work once - after that it just console.log's the code.

```
const [modalState, setModalState] = useState({
    showModal: false,
    videoUrl: '',
  });

  const openModal = () => {
    setModalState({
      ...modalState,
      showModal: (prev) => !prev,
    });
    console.log(modalState.showModal);
  };
```

On the first click the console logs 'false' and opens the modal. On the second click the console logs 'prev => !prev' and seems to do nothing.

I'm pretty sure it will be an easy syntax issue but I'm struggling to find the right guide. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of `useState()`, you get the entire state, which is an object in your case. Since an object is a truthy value, `!prev` would always be `false`.

When using the functional update option you should update the entire object. In addition, you won't see the changes until the next render, so move the `console.log()` to the body of the component.

```
const [modalState, setModalState] = useState({
  showModal: false,
  videoUrl: '',
});

const openModal = () => {
  setModalState(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    showModal: !prev.showModal,
  }));
}; 

console.log(modalState.showModal);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the explanation of functional updates is very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer solved your problem, you should accept it - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: The code I posted in the answer above was the solution I needed but your answer helped me understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking - I managed to find the answer whilst going through a separate tutorial.

I needed to change the

```
showModal: (prev) => !prev,
```

to:

```
showModal: !modalState.showModal,
```

This is now working.